# Android Device Administrator / Profile owner

Tags: android, certificate, device-admin, profile-owner

I'm trying to know how Device Administrator and Profile Owner works. I followed some examples from google website, but I still do not quite know how profile owner works.

To test this, I've built a sample app which will ask the user to accept the Profile Owner and then will install a certificate without user interaction.

For the request of the profile owner I did this on my activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_PROVISION_MANAGED_PROFILE);
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_PACKAGE_NAME, getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_PROVISION_MANAGED_PROFILE);
```

On my receiver I have something like this:

```
@Override
public void onProfileProvisioningComplete(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // Enable the profile
    DevicePolicyManager manager =
            (DevicePolicyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
    ComponentName componentName = getComponentName(context);
    manager.setProfileName(componentName, context.getString(R.string.profile_name));

    // If I do not do this, the application will not enter in profile mode, and I don't know why 
    Intent launch = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    launch.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(launch);
}
```

In here I don't know why I need to restart application so I can enter in profile owner mode. 
Although, when I get the profile owner working and I close the app and start it again I will not resume the profile owner mode.

I'm checking if the profile owner mode is active by doing something like this on application OnCreate() method:

```
  if (!mDeviceController.isProfileActive()) {
      Log.i("DeviceAdminSample", "Profile is disabled!!!!!");
  }
```

Why is profile owner disabled when I restart the application? Is there any way to avoid a user enabling the profile owner mode every single time he opens the application?

Additionally, If I install a certificate with this mechanism, other apps can still use this certificate, or the certificate will only work for the created profile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are missing:

```
manager.setProfileEnabled(componentName);
```

I recommend looking a little closer at some of the examples below. I'm not sure what `isProfileActive()` does. I would use:

```
manager.isProfileOwnerApp(getApplicationContext().getPackage())
```

When you create a managed profile, the managed profile's apps and data are separate from the user's apps/data that created the managed profile (in most cases, personal versus work). If you open your app from the original user's context, it will try to set up a work profile again. To see your app as the profile owner, you need to open it in your managed profile's context (your app will be "badge", have a little briefcase on it). Additionally, data like your certificates will be restricted to your managed profile.

- https://developer.android.com/work/managed-profiles.html
- https://developers.google.com/android/work/build-dpc

A good initial example to follow:
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BasicManagedProfile

A much more complex, but more complete example. It can be configured as a device owner or profile owner:
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testdpc