# Admin does not own the profile

Tags: android, kotlin, admin

I'm trying to write an app to block the user from restoring the phone to factory settings or resetting the settings.
The problem is that the app activates as administrator, but displays an error about lack of permissions. At the same time, when clicking on "Block Wipe Data," the app shuts down.

I have tried various ways to change the permissions of the application from profile owner to device owner, but without success
This is my MainActivity.kt:

```
package com.example.test2

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.app.admin.DevicePolicyManager
import android.content.ComponentName
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.UserManager
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.example.test2.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var devicePolicyManager: DevicePolicyManager
    private lateinit var componentName: ComponentName
    private val disallowFactoryReset = "no_factory_reset"


    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    @SuppressLint("WrongConstant")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        devicePolicyManager = getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE) as DevicePolicyManager
        componentName = ComponentName(this, MyDeviceAdminReceiver::class.java)

        // Ustawienie tekstu przycisków na podstawie zasobów ciągów
        binding.activateButton.setText(R.string.activate_button_text)
        binding.deactivateButton.setText(R.string.deactivate_button_text)
        binding.blockWipeDataButton.setText(R.string.block_wipe_data_button_text)
        binding.unblockWipeDataButton.setText(R.string.unblock_wipe_data_button_text)

        binding.activateButton.setOnClickListener {
            if (!devicePolicyManager.isAdminActive(componentName)) {
                val intent = Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN)
                intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN, componentName)
                startActivity(intent) // Uruchamianie intencji
            }
        }

        binding.deactivateButton.setOnClickListener {
            if (devicePolicyManager.isAdminActive(componentName)) {
                devicePolicyManager.removeActiveAdmin(componentName)
            }
        }

        binding.blockWipeDataButton.setOnClickListener {
            // Blokowanie możliwości resetowania do ustawień fabrycznych
                devicePolicyManager.addUserRestriction(componentName, UserManager.DISALLOW_FACTORY_RESET)
            }


        binding.unblockWipeDataButton.setOnClickListener {
            if (devicePolicyManager.isAdminActive(componentName)) {
                // Odblokowywanie możliwości resetowania do ustawień fabrycznych
                devicePolicyManager.clearUserRestriction(componentName, disallowFactoryReset)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

MyDeviceAdminReceiver.kt:

```
package com.example.test2

import android.app.admin.DeviceAdminReceiver
import android.app.admin.DevicePolicyManager
import android.content.ComponentName
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.widget.Toast

class MyDeviceAdminReceiver : DeviceAdminReceiver() {
    override fun onEnabled(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        super.onEnabled(context, intent)
        showToast(context, "Device Admin Enabled")
        setAsProfileOwner(context)
    }

    override fun onDisabled(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        super.onDisabled(context, intent)
        showToast(context, "Device Admin Disabled")
    }

    private fun showToast(context: Context, msg: String) {
        Toast.makeText(context, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

    private fun setAsProfileOwner(context: Context) {
        val intent = Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_PROVISION_MANAGED_PROFILE)
        intent.putExtra(
            DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_COMPONENT_NAME,
            ComponentName(context, MyDeviceAdminReceiver::class.java)
        )
        context.startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

And AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.test2">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DEVICE_ADMINS"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_PROFILE_AND_DEVICE_OWNERS"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Test2">

        <receiver
            android:name=".MyDeviceAdminReceiver"
            android:label="@string/device_admin"
            android:description="@string/device_admin_description"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN"
            android:exported="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.device_admin"
                android:resource="@xml/device_admin_receiver" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Ok, app is working correctly, it is blocking factory reset. This https://stackoverflow.com/a/42119378/23369606

```
adb shell 
dpm set-device-owner com.foo.deviceowner/.DeviceAdminRcvr
```

method helps a lot, i just needed to make it device owner, but is there any chance to make app device owner WITHOUT deleting all existing accounts? There is no problem with new phones, but if I need to make it work on the phone that is already in use?

Comment: How did you provisioned your device?

Comment: samsung a10 - not owned by any organization, after factory reset, without any accounts activated

Comment: I mean how did you make your app device or profile owner?

Comment: I think this is the problem too, cause i can't do it
I'm using DevicePolicyManager and UserManager, but i don't have idea how to do that

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/42119378/769265

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44023646/android-device-administrator-profile-owner

Comment: I think this method: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42119378/769265 helps, app might have permissions, but blocking wipe data is still not working

Comment: First make sure you provisioned device the right way. Then your code works. You also need to make phone device owner, profile owner privilages isn't enough

Comment: I used adb shell and dpm set-device-owner and there is no longer error with Admin Componentinfo, but now, while i'm clicking 'Block Wipe Data' or 'Unblock Wipe Data' i have only "ViewPostIme pointer 0/1" in Logcat and nothing happens. Like buttons did nothing.
And I also edited my code a little bit, so you can tell me wthat's wrong